# My aloe plants turned grey when I took it outside

Tags: plant-care, aloe

I brought my happy green aloe plants outside for sunshine and they all turned a sickly gray color. What happened and can I reverse it?

Comment: Got a picture?  It would help with diagnosis.

Answer (score 6):

Too much sun, no easy, slow transition from dim inside light to right out in the harsh sun - Aloes really hate that, IME.

Put the poor things in the shade and give them time. Eventually they can be out in full sun, but they need time to adapt to it.

More generally, this is a case of needing "hardening off" for the transition.